# Best way to get 256 io pins?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, io

I'm connecting to an arduino or raspberry pi and would like to have 256 io pins. I found a 16bit io expander which has 8 unique addresses for 128 but that's the max I can do on i2c. Any other thoughts on how to expand my io ports?

Comment: ... another I2C bus?

Comment: @Majenko  To be fair, I think this question would still hold if you replace Raspberry Pi or Arduino with MSP430 or some such appropriate μC.

Comment: Can you describe your application in more detail? There might be a way that doesn't require 256 i/o pins.

Comment: -1 for lack of detail.

Comment: Do you need I/O pins, or unidirectional inputs or outputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put an I2C Multiplexer in there between the Arduino and your devices, then only put one of each address on each downstream bus. A 1-to-2 Multiplexer that I've used with Arduino before is [PCA9540BD,118](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PCA9540BD,118/568-1844-1-ND/789976). That will get you to 256 with the hardware and interfaces you are already using with the addition of one more component.

Answer (score 6):

There are inexpensive CPLDs available with lots of I/O pins. It's a good tool to have in your toolbox. For example, XC2C32A with 33 I/O for $1.25. Or slap down a $50-ish XC2C512 with 270 I/O and it's all over but the programming.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution if all you are looking for is low-speed output-only: 74HC595.
http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf

I once used this chip for animating a lot of LEDs.

You can connect a chain of these chips together, so that the output of a Q7S goes to it's neighbor's DS. Then, take an SPI output of your main micro and connect it to the chain. The micro's SPI-MOSI should connect to the free DS chip and then SPI-CLK should connect, in parallel, to all of the SHCP pins. Then, use a free I/O to pulse all of the STCP pins. Your transmission should look like this:

1. Transmit 8 bytes on SPI.
2. Pulse STCP

Once you pulse the STCP line, all of the outputs will change.

Answer (score 2):

The MCP23S17 has 16 I/O pins and uses SPI. Throw in a 4:16 demux for the select and you get 256 I/Os.

Answer (score 2):

Both MCP23017 and 23S17 have addresses so 8 23017's on I2C and 8 23S17's sharing one SPI bus.